# Creating a post commit when using transaction in Spring

Tags: java, spring, transactions

Due to certain reasons i have manually performed transaction commit and roll back using Spring PlatformTransactionManager, what i need to do is setup a hook so that a post commit action takes place after transaction has been committed.

By looking at:

```
 void commit(TransactionStatus status) throws TransactionException;
```

I cant see how i can determine a transaction was successful other than assumming it so if no expception are thrown.

And i could use AOP as one option, but what about programmitcally doing it, maybe using  callback method?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You could get exactly what you want by a simpler way, with [`TransactionSynchronizationManager`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationManager.html) and [`TransactionSynchronization`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronization.html)

With `TransactionSynchronizationManager`, you have static methods to get information about current transaction, and you can register a `TransactionSynchronization` wich allows you to automatically do a post-commit as you call that

```
TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronization(){
           void afterCommit(){
                //do what you want to do after commit
           }
})
```

Be aware that the TransactionSynchronization is on a per-thread basis (which is often not a problem for a basic web request).

Comment: okay this seems quite nice... so if its bound to single thread, and call is recursive... say a single thread starts a transaction registers a synchronisation(1 - after commit) and then calls another method who joins that transaction registers a synchronisation(2 - after commit).... when it commits.. i think only one after commit synchroniser would be fired... due to them being stored in a set?.. maybe im wrong i would have to test...

Comment: `TransactionSynchronization` objects are kept as a list by thread, list that you can retrieve with `TransactionSynchronizationManager.getSynchronizations()`

Comment: i believe its kept as a set, and then returned as a list... Set<TransactionSynchronization> synchs.............. return new ArrayList<TransactionSynchronization>(synchs)..... im just thinking two after commits would fire...

Comment: I have wrote a blog post about  transaction synchronization in Spring and how to easily register after commit callbacks http://azagorneanu.blogspot.com/2013/06/transaction-synchronization-callbacks.html

Comment: Use `TransactionSynchronizationAdapter` as a cleaner way of implementing single methods.

Comment: The above implementation needs to override all methods of `TransactionSynchronization` even though it shows only one. Check my answer based on @Alex suggestion

Comment: @Alex since Spring 5, `TransactionSynchronization` now using `default` for its methods. So, no need to use `TransactionSynchronizationAdapter`

Comment: The signature should have public visibility in order to override the default method.

Comment: The doc of TransactionSynchronizationManager tells "To be used by resource management code but not by typical application code". So, essentially you should not use it.

Comment: @Christian what should you use instead?

Comment: Scroll down a bit to Frank Wilson's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62722827

Answer (score 34):

Credit to Grooveek's answer and Alex's comment under it - I put this here because the combined suggestions provide a solid and cleaner solution that is hard to find around the net.

Using Spring 4+. if you need a callback on a `@Transactional` method after it successfully commits just add that in the beginning of the method:

```
@Service
public class OneService {

    @Autowired
    OneDao dao;

    @Transactional
    public void a transactionalMethod() {
        TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronization(){
            public void afterCommit(){
                //do stuff right after commit
                System.out.println("commit!!!");
                
            }
        });
        //do db stuff
        dao.save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to @Michail for his answer. For transactional roll-backs this approach works using "afterCompletion(int status)" and checking status == TransactionSynchronization. STATUS_ROLLED_BACK

Comment: TransactionSynchronizationAdapter is deprecated. You can just replace it with TransactionSynchronization in this code example.

Answer (score 22):

Since Spring 4.2 it has been possible to define listeners for post commit events (or more generally transaction synchronization events e.g. rollbacks) using annotation based configuraton. This is based off event handling in [core spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#context-functionality-events). It is easier to test code using this approach since you avoid a direct dependency on TransactionSynchronizationManager, which will likely not be active in a unit test. You can easily test that your transactional service publishes an event and also that your listener performs the right action when you receive an event.

So without further ado this is how to set it up:

In this example we'll assume you have a `Customer` entity and a `CustomerRepository` (and ORM to go with it).

First you need a new event type `NewCustomerEvent`:

```
// NewCustomerEvent.java
// Just a regular pojo for the event
public class NewCustomerEvent {

    public String email;

    // constructor, setters and getters omitted
}
```

Then you define a listener using [`@TransactionalEventListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/event/TransactionalEventListener.html). By default this will execute after a sucessful commit but this can be changed using the `phase` parameter:

```
// NewCustomerEventListener.java
@Component
public class NewCustomerEventListener {

    @TransactionalEventListener
    public void handleNewCustomerEvent(NewCustomerEvent newCustomerEvent) {
        // handle new customer event
    }
}
```

Finally you augment your transaction service with an [`ApplicationEventPublisher`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationEventPublisher.html) on which you call publish once all the transaction statements have been sent.

```
// CustomerRespositoryService.java
@Service
public class CustomerRepositoryService {

    @Inject
    private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

    @Inject
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void createCustomer(String email) {
        Customer customer = new Customer(email);
        customerRespotory.save(customer);
        applicationEventPublisher.publish(new NewCustomerEvent(email));
    }

}
```

See also:

- https://dzone.com/articles/simpler-handling-of-asynchronous-transaction-bound
- https://dzone.com/articles/transaction-synchronization-and-spring-application

Comment: Definitely a cleaner way for 2020

Comment: Small precision, the annotation for the listener is TransactionalEventListener and not TransactionalListener

Comment: @F. Geraerts good catch, thanks! It should be corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

In one of my projects because of certain reasons I also had to use `PlatformTransactionManager`. So I forced to use `org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate`.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html

The main benefit is that if you have implemented PlatformTransactionManager correctly, you don't need to bother with manual commit/rollback. At least source code of TransactionTemplate may help you if you need more specific thing.

It's pretty simply to use:

config.xml

```
<bean name="transactionTemplate"
            class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="platformTransactionManager"/>
</bean>
```

MyServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Autowired
    private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

    public Entity getSomethingWithTx(final long id) {

        return transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback&lt;Entity>() {
            @Override
            public Entity doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
                //TODO implement
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats really helps with the manual coding side of things, but how is it possible to tell wether a transaction has been rolled back or committed succesfully, i can see status.iscompleted().. but that could mean a successful roll back or a successful commit...?

Comment: Transaction will rollback here in two cases only: callback code throws an exception which leaves doInTransaction or there is an implicit rollback call (which is strongly discouraged and will probably generate an UnexpectedRollbackException). Therefore you can safely assume if getSomethingWithTx did not throw an exceptin, the transaction committed successfully.

Comment: not that applicable and extremely wordy which is main reasons you use `@Transactional` is to cut bloat like that from code