# Making a HTTP call from a java application coupled with a spring transaction manager

Tags: java, spring, http, transactions, spring-transactions

Here's the situation. I have an application that's working fine with the transactionmanager that i'm using. what i need to do is post some information onto another application in the form of http calls at certain stages. What i want to happen is for the http calls to be made only when the transaction completes successfully. And if the transaction fails for some reason (Some Exception) then the http call should not be made.

Any suggestions on how this can be done?

is there a way where during the course of my code i can register these http calls and when the transaction manager completes successfully, these http calls are made.

Answer (score 1):

Spring provides a clean way of handling callback events via [TransactionSynchronization](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronization.html). This registers hooks for various transaction events (*After commit, On completion etc*).

Here is a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026142/creating-a-post-commit-when-using-transaction-in-spring) which address your problem. Here is [another link](http://sathyasekar.wordpress.com/2009/09/14/transaction-callbacks-from-spring/).

Comment: Thanks!! Will have a look and see how it goes !!

Answer (score 0):

Don't do the http call directly, rather (in your JTA transaction) post a message to JMS/XA. That way, the message will be available to consumers only when the transaction commits.

Then, add a HTTP consumer that takes a message, and does the http call. As per the JMS/XA semantics, it will only get messages of committed transactions at the sender.

If you want a free JTA transaction manager then check out https://www.atomikos.com

Best

Guy Pardon