# Spring Transaction: How is there a way to auto evict after transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate

I just committed a very large data and i wish to evict all the data after the Transaction.

Is there anything I can add to @Transaction to make it auto evict apart from calling evict manually?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a `Post commit action`. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026142/creating-a-post-commit-when-using-transaction-in-spring) can help you.