# Spring @Transactional multiple threads

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have a method A running in the transactional scope which:

1. Modifies an entity A to switch from state A to state B
2. Passes a task to a executor service that expects an Entity to be in state B when executed

The problem is when this task is run (that thing I have no control of) before the method A commits, it doesn't see the required state changed because it does not block until the method A level transaction ends.

Task is run using a spring bean and @Transactional-annotated method like this:

```
@Service
public class TransactionalProcessingAdapter implements ProcessingAdapter {

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void execute(ProcessingAdaptedMethod processingAdapter) {
        processingAdapter.execute();
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a post commit when using transaction in Spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026142/creating-a-post-commit-when-using-transaction-in-spring)

Comment: I am bit confused. You start a transaction in a method and, in the body of that method, you execute a task in another thread and expects it to see what you have changed. You can't really do that, you should either change your transaction boundaries or fallback on a programmatic use of the transaction (using `TransactionTemplate`)

Comment: So long story short there is no way of doing this using annotations? How about using JTA/XA? The thing is this is only a part of a problem - the other part is I use JMS too, but only one database. In some cases I'd like to fallback if JMS-invoked method fails.

Comment: The thing is I'd like the second thread to wait until the transaction in the first thread is completed...

Comment: My point is that you can't see what you have done in another thread. This has nothing to do with Spring or the transaction manager that you use. Even if in some edge case, there's a way to make it work, a transaction is private to its thread.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that Spring transactions are thread bounded - eg a transaction is visible inside its initial threads only. ThreadLocal is used to implement that property.

You might want to implement your own TransactionSynchronizationManager in Spring and inject it. Use something like InheritableThreadLocal instead of ThreadLocal.