# Spring hibernate , how to call some method after transaction commit or transaction rollback

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I need to call some method after transaction succes or rollback. I am using as

```
    <bean name="openSessionInViewInterceptor" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
                <property name="sessionFactory">
                    <ref local="mysessionFactory"/>
                </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="mysessionFactory"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

The application use some external web services which needs to be "cleaned" when the internal transaction gets rollbacked. 
Is there way how to accomplish this without using declarative transaction management.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

- From Hibernate, you could extends `EmptyInterceptor` and override
  `afterTransactionCompletion()` method and register it in
  `SessionFactoryBean` or `HibernateTransactionManager`.
- From Spring you could extends `TransactionSynchronizationAdapter` and
  override `afterCompletion()` and register when appropriate with
  `TransactionSynchronizationManager#registerSynchronization()`.

**Edit**

An Example of using Spring Aop to add a synchronization to all  methods annotated with `@Transactional`

```
@Aspect
class TransactionAspect extends TransactionSynchronizationAdapter {

    @Before("@annotation(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)")
    public void registerTransactionSyncrhonization() {
        TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(int status) {
        // code 
    }
}
```

Comment: that works and as  I have allredy extended EmptyInterceptor it was easy and  it is good for catching roll backs. I need to solve the other part which will be removing candidates for web service "cleaning" becouse afterTransactionCompletion() is called after each commit (they can be nested ). So I can't determine if the whole transaction chain will succes before response is sent to client.

Comment: If transaction is in scope, you can get transaction info from `TransactionAspectSupport#currentTransactionStatus()`, however I think that spring only call afterCompletion() once. I added a sample Aspect to apply Synchronization for annotation driven transaction demarcation.

Comment: while an `Aspect` may be good for global configuration for all `@Transactional` methods,  a method-based callback approach is provided in my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43322119/986160

Comment: TransactionSynchronizationAdapter is deprecated.

Answer (score 24):

Spring has various classes which might be of interest here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronization.html

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationAdapter.html

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationManager.html

There's some example code here:

http://azagorneanu.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/transaction-synchronization-callbacks.html

---

### Update 2016

The event handling infrastructure introduced in Spring 4.2 makes this much simpler.

See:

https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2#transaction-bound-events

> Another popular improvement is the ability to bind the listener of an
>   event to a phase of the transaction. The typical example is to handle
>   the event when the transaction has completed successfully

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {

  @TransactionalEventListener(condition = "#creationEvent.awesome")
  public void handleOrderCreatedEvent(CreationEvent<Order> creationEvent) { 
    ...
  }

}
```

> `@TransactionalEventListener` is a regular `@EventListener` and also
>   exposes a TransactionPhase, the default being AFTER_COMMIT. You can
>   also hook other phases of the transaction (BEFORE_COMMIT,
>   AFTER_ROLLBACK and AFTER_COMPLETION that is just an alias for
>   AFTER_COMMIT and AFTER_ROLLBACK).

Comment: Do you have any examples of how the TransactionalEventListener works/how you would implement it? It seems like it is what I need to solve my issue but the documentation on it is sparse.

Comment: @tallkid24 - Here is a quick gist from a project i am working on https://gist.github.com/mrasband/a36cf9bedce9fe39338e2641694e3502

Answer (score 19):

Using Spring 4+: The easiest/cleanest way without using global aspects and configurations is based on my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43322052/986160

If you need a callback on a `@Transactional` method after it successfully commits just add that in the beginning of the method:

```
@Service
public class OneService {

    @Autowired
    OneDao dao;

    @Transactional
    public void a transactionalMethod() {
        TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter(){
            public void afterCommit(){
                //do stuff right after commit
                System.out.println("commit!!!");

            }
        });
        //do db stuff
        dao.save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to @Michail for his answer. For transactional roll-backs this approach works using "afterCompletion(int status)" and checking status == TransactionSynchronization. STATUS_ROLLED_BACK

Comment: For spring boot 2.2.13 it is deprecated