# Retry Interval in IBM MQ Queues

Tags: ibm-mq, spring-jms

We have JMS Listeners implemented in Spring which are listening to a Queues created on IBM MQ. Since we have multiple resources e.g. MQ, Database we are using JTA transaction manager which in case of transaction rollbacks puts message back on queue. Though we could configure retry count using back-out threshold property of queue, i could not find anything that lets us configure retry interval. Do you have any experience implementing the same ? if no direct solution any workaround which can be easily applied ?

Comment: Is this any use ? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.con.doc/q082070_.htm

Comment: thanks and sorry for responding bit late. This seems to be applicable to the PUT operations only. Whereas when using JMS Listeners we need to consider retry on GET operations.

Comment: We tried fixing this issue by implementing solution mentioned at link = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651464/spring-hibernate-how-to-call-some-method-after-transaction-commit-or-transacti however it did not help.

Comment: Finally we resolved it by adding a delay in the ErrorHandler.handleError() method. Whenever message processing results in a error, thread sleeps for the x seconds and acknowledgement is sent after x seconds (where x is the retry interval we wanted to set.)