# How to identify a Model object got commited into db

Tags: java, hibernate, web-services

I am working on a project for cashback thing, so whenever any transaction getting successful i need to notify a service.

I am using java, hibernate.

I have tried to notify service whenever object getting saved (not commit), but that object getting saved many time in the overall flow, so i don't want to notify service many time.

My goal is to notify only once when that object finally got persisted in db.

So is there any way that i can put some kind of observer, that will tell that object got committed?

Comment: are you using spring to handle transactions? show a piece of transactional method of yours

Comment: If you are using Spring Transactions for Transaction management check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651464/spring-hibernate-how-to-call-some-method-after-transaction-commit-or-transacti

Comment: Or you could have a trigger run on the DB

Comment: i am not using spring, actually we have very old financial system build in Struts 1.3 and hibernate 4. Through that all the transactions happening.