# Automatically call method in each JPA transaction

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions

I want to call a method (that calls a Postgres function) every time a transaction is started.

I'm not sure where to start, but I'm using JpaTransactionManager.

Comment: JPA is just a specification, you are using a particular implementation such as Hibernate. That implementation will have a way to add a listener so you can hook into the lifecycle of a transaction.

Comment: See hear for an outline on Spring's support for hooking into the transaction lifecycle. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651464/spring-hibernate-how-to-call-some-method-after-transaction-commit-or-transacti/23653651#23653651

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Approach to that would be:

Create a Class that replaces the JPATransactionManager by delegating all calls to a hidden local instance of JPATransactionManager.
This class additionally can provide the possibility to register observers.
When configuring your Spring-Container use this new class instead of JPATransactionManager, all begin Transaction-Calls should be routed through that.

Depending on the solution of the Transaction-Object, if you want to be sure, that you catch all begin calls, you can create a delegate to the transaction-object returned by the TransactionManager as well and return this delegate by your TransactionManager-Delegate.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to use Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP). AOP will help you to write your method once and define a pointcut. 
What's AOP? you can read [What's AOP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746676/logging-with-aop-in-spring)