# Waiting for transaction to finish in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Consider following (pseudo-kotlin) code:

```
@Transactional
fun updateDatabase(entity: Entity) {
    // do something with entity
}

fun kafkaProduce() {
    updateDatabase(entity) 
    kafka.sendMessage(entity.id)
}

fun kafkaConsume(entityId: Long) {
    em.find(Entity::class, entityId)
}
```

Our problem is that we use isolation level `READ UNCOMMITTED` which normally is just fine. When calling `kafkaProduce` it happens that `kafkaConsume` is called before the transaction in `updateDatabase` finishes and it reads the old state of the Entity. Is there a way to do some kind of `em.waitForCompletion` so that the transaction really finishes before sending the message to Kafka?

Comment: Is the same thread first calling `kafkaProduce` and then `kafkaConsume`? If yes, `@Transactional(REQUIRES_NEW)` or similar on both methods helps

Comment: I don't think this will be the same thread. Also these are separate transactions, they are not inside of each other, so I don't think, this would help.

Comment: If you are using Spring then you can register a listener to execute when the transaction has completed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23653651/1356423

Comment: "I don't think this will be the same thread" - so, you want to synchronize concurrent access? Seems like a plan to introduce a major bottleneck into your application.

Comment: Besides, in JEE context, there is no such thing as nested transactions. Only mutually exclusive, either suspended/pending or active transactions.

Comment: @AlanHay you saved me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution thanks to AlanHay:

```java
    @Transactional
    public void a transactionalMethod() {
        TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter(){
            public void afterCommit(){
                //do stuff right after commit
                System.out.println("commit!!!");

            }
        });

        //do db stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are different transactions then you might need to use **Pessimistic Locking**:

```
fun updateDatabase(entity: Entity) {
   Entity entityMerged = entityManager.merge(entity);
   entityManager.lock(entityMerged, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
```

This would create a physical lock on the database row. When other transaction will try to query this one and the first one is still not finished, it will get `PessimisticLockException`.

Then you can catch it and try to recover until the lock is released.

**Just be careful** not to overuse this strategy and test it really well before going into production. It may become a bottleneck if the traffic is heavy.