# How can I extend and add more functionality to Transaction advise of Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I am using Spring Transactions and my service classes are annotated with
@Transactional annotation. 
I want to add some code before and after transaction commit/rollback without adding a new Aspect, So i want to extend the Aspect which Spring uses internally and make Spring Transaction use that Transaction advice instead of the default one.

Comment: Hi, you can try to register some callbacks for commit/rollback (http://stackoverflow.com/a/15026797/1905015), but without your actual requirements it is hard to help you here...

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using TransactionListener provided by Springs.
@TransactionEventListner takes options like BEFORE_COMMIT, AFTER_COMMIT, AFTER_ROLLBACK, AFTER_COMPLETION. This indicate when the listener should trigger the event.

Spring provides this for handling cases where the post/pre txn commit/rollback has to be handled.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-event