# A call to an async method which participates in caller's transaction

Tags: java, spring

I have a transactional method (method annotated with springs @Transactional) in which I want to call a method which is annotated with @Async.

I want the call to be part of the current transaction meaning if the current transaction is rolled back, the async method is never executed. The execution of the async method should not participate in the callers transaction.

It is comparable to calling a JMS Queue with a connection which participates in the current XA transaction.

Some code to ilustrate this:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Component
public class Caller {

    @Autowired 
    HeavyWork heavyWork;

    @Transactional
    public void distribute(String job,boolean success) {
        heavyWork.doWork("first job "+job);
        // other stuff which may cause the current transaction to fail, here simulated by a boolean
        if(!success)
            throw new RuntimeException("no way");
    }
}
```

and the called async method:

```
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Component
public class HeavyWork {

    @Async
    public void doWork(String text) {
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

With the current code if I call `distribute("job 1", false)` the `doWork()` method is executed.

Question: is there a way block the async call 'till the transaction is committed. Maybe an in-memory lightweight queue implementation which supports transactions ?

Spring version: 5.3

Comment: If you are blocking what is the purpose of making it async in the first place? Apparently you don't want it to be async. Next to that transaction propagation over multiple threads (let alone session, connection reuse over threads) will be painful.

Comment: You don't understand it correctly. The call to the async method should participate in the transaction but not the execution of the async method (which is executed in a separate thread). This can be achieved by calling a JMS Queue using a XAConnectionfactory but I'm searching for a more lightweight solution.

Comment: You are comparing apples/oranges. Placing something on a queue is not the same as participating in a transaction. The message will only be published on commit, the outcome of the listener (on the other end of the queue) doesn't have any influence on the transaction that just committed. Judging from your description this is what you want. If that isn't what you want to achieve then re-write your question to clarify that better.

Comment: The comparison with JMS and an XA connection is exactly what I want but then without the overhead of an external message broker. Please read my answer with the ApplciationEventPublisher, which does it correctly. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution can be the org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher. The `applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(param)` method can be called within the transaction but the event listeners implementation is only called when the transaction commits.

See [Creating a post commit when using transaction in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026142/creating-a-post-commit-when-using-transaction-in-spring)

In the implementation I can make an Async call and thus this will only be called when the transaction committed:

```
@Component
public class TaskIndexCommandEventListener {
    @Autowired 
    private TaskIndexer taskIndexer;

    /**
     * after commit to asure we only reindex after the transaction completed so the indexer will find the last information in the DB. 
     * @param newCommand
     */
    @TransactionalEventListener(phase = TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMMIT)
    public void handleNewIndexCommand(TaskIndexCommand newCommand) {
        taskIndexer.performCommand(newCommand);
    }
}
```

The TaskIndexer's method is annotated with @Async:

```
@Component
public class TaskIndexer {
    @Async
    public void performCommand(TaskIndexCommand event) {
      // do the async stuff here which is executed only 
      // after the transaction is committed and does not participate in it.
    }
```

Still interested in alternative solutions if any.

Comment: This will only work in conjucting with an `@TransactionalEventListener` and not with a traditional `@EventListener`. So this answer is only partly correct and doesn't provide the full solution.

Comment: I never said EventListener was a requirement. If you know a full solution it will be much appreciated if you could post it here as an answer. Otherwise please don't let me waiste your time any further.

Comment: You posted this as an answer but it doesn't solve your issue, hence it isn't an answer. If you want to use the event listener you need the aforementioned `@TransactionalEventListener` and not a regular `@EventListener` or `ApplicationListner` as that would be like a normal method call (sync and direct instead of delayed to transaction commit);

Comment: ok, valid point. I've updated my answer with the extra async call.