# When is Transaction getting committed when using @Transactional

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I have a spring boot service class method which is annotated with @Transactional, where I will need to
commit the transaction to MYSQL DB and then execute the finally block of code which is to push the entity to a Redis queue. Below is my code snippet:

```
@Transactional
public void save(Entity t) {
    try {
         entityRepository.save(t);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
         log.error("Error while executing transaction",e);
    } finally {
        //code to push to redis
    }
}
```

My doubt is whether the transaction will be committed and the finally block will be executed? Or the @Transactional will complete all the transaction only after the finally block completes. If it is the latter, how do I ensure that my transaction is committed before pushing to Redis?

Please advice.

**NOTE:** entityRepository is a class which extends CrudRepository

Answer (score 2):

The transaction will be commited only after the finally block.

For the use case mentioned look at: [Creating a post commit when using transaction in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026142/creating-a-post-commit-when-using-transaction-in-spring)

Register a TransactionSynchronization with an afterCommit or afterCompletion.