# Can't get the updated entity with spring jpa and unique constrain doesn't stop the update

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, transactions, spring-data

My situation: a public method is trying to update the entity in the beginning, and at last, it is trying to query the updated entity and send a message via SNS. I got two issues with this.

The first issue is I can get the updated entity if I call the `DeviceDao.save()` but can't get the updated entity if I call the customized update method `updateAsset` in the `UpdateClass`.

The second issue is the code still goes through to the messagePublisher and I can get the updated entity in 'MessagePublisher.doRealthing()' even the `UpdateClass.doSth()` throw a org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException(I have an unique constraint on asset id), but eventually, the update is rollbacked.

My question is, why did I get that two issues? For the second issue, How can I avoid it except by querying the asset Id in advance?

Here are my codes.

```
public interface ExampleDeviceDao extends JpaRepository<Device, UUID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Device> {

    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE device a SET a.asset = ?1 WHERE a.device = ?2")
    int updateAsset(UUID asset, UUID device);

}
```

My public service and method:

```
@Component
public class Service {
    @Autowired
    UpdateClass updateClass;
    @Autowired
    MiddleClass middleClass;
    @Autowired
    MessagePublisher messagePublisher;

    @org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
    public void updateAsset(UUID deviceId, UUID assetId) {
        updateClass.doSth(deviceId, assetId);
        middleClass.doSth(deviceId, assetId);
        messagePublisher.doSth(deviceId, assetId);
    }
}
```

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {

    protected abstract void doRealThing(UUID deviceId, UUID assetId);

    public void doSth(UUID deviceId, UUID assetId) {
        doRealThing(deviceId, assetId);
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class UpdateClass extends AbstractClass{

    @Autowired
    ExampleDeviceDao deviceDao;

    protected void doRealThing(UUID deviceId, UUID assetId) {
        Optional<Device> device = deviceDao.findById(deviceId);
        if (device.isPresent()) {
            device.get().setAsset(assetId);
            /** approach 1:*/
            deviceDao.save(device.get());
            /**
             * approach 2:
             * deviceDao.updateAsset(assetId, deviceId);
             */
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class MiddleClass extends AbstractClass{


    protected void doRealThing(UUID deviceId, UUID assetId) {
        //do other things, not db update or query.
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class MessagePublisher extends AbstractClass{

    @Autowired
    ExampleDeviceDao deviceDao;
    @Autowired
    SNSMessagePublisher snsMessagePublisher;

    protected void doRealThing(UUID deviceId, UUID assetId) {
        Optional<Device> device = deviceDao.findById(deviceId);
        if (device.isPresent()) {
            snsMessagePublisher.publishMessage(device.get());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @JensSchauder Sorry. My question is, why did I get that two issues? For the second issue, How can I avoid it except querying the asset Id in advance?

Answer (score 2):

The problem probably is that your first level cache (a.k.a. persistence context) contains the entity which you are executing a DML statement (`update device ...`) against. Hibernate has no knowledge though, that your DML statement will change the state of an entity in the persistence context and can also not do anything sensible about this. So the changes are executed on the database, but the entity in the persistence context still has the old state. The only sensible things you can do are to refresh the entity (if you need it), or remove it from the persistence context by calling `EntityManager.detach()`.

As far as I understand your second question, your publisher code publishes the SNS message even though the database transaction fails. In this case you will always have a possible issue as the SNS client is not part of the transaction and also can't be.

You can send messages after a transaction completes by

- Calling the publisher after the `@Transactional` method returns
- Register a transactional post commit callback, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15026797/412446

This has the possibility that you might miss sending some messages if the JVM shuts down after a transaction completes but didn't send the SNS message yet, or if the SNS message sending fails for some reason.

To solve such issues, you'd usually use some sort of job queuing that has retry mechanisms. If you are interested in a solution for this, you can take a look at [Blaze-Notify](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-notify) which is a tool kit that can be used to implement this efficiently. Instead of sending the SNS message immediately, you persist an entity that represents the message, which will then later be processed asynchronously and sent with a retry mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the first part of the puzzle. Regrading the second part — a SNS client is a part of the transaction.  It was really hard, for me, to understand that the second part is related to the sources that is not from the first part.  SNS client can be part of transaction, from my experience. The retry mechanics can be applied before transactional method in this case. So SNS message will be sent again with database changes committed again. But it is not for the case from the question, because validation error can't be retried.

Comment: I don't think you understand what it means for something to be "part of a transaction". If the SNS part was a resource that is part of the transaction, it wouldn't be executed when the database parts fail. Also look into the 2 phase commit concept if you want to understand what this is about. Sending the message possibly multiple times or not at all is exactly what can happen when you are not using some sort of queuing.

Answer (score 1):

For the first issue see the @ChristianBeikov [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73359318/3405171).

The second issue has the same reason as the first one.
You do

```java
begin of updateAsset() method

device.get().setAsset(assetId); (1)
/** approach 1:*/
deviceDao.save(device.get()); (2)

Optional<Device> device = deviceDao.findById(deviceId); (3)
snsMessagePublisher.publishMessage(device.get()); (4)


end of updateAsset() method (5)
```

1. You change device in the memory (persistent context).
2. You save device to a database. Actually Hibernate does nothing at this point. You can enable SQL logging and see that nothing happens.
3. You get `Device` from a database. Hibernate again does nothing with the database here. It just gets it from the memory with the changes you have made at (1) step. Please verify it using SQL logs.
4. Changed `Device` is sent to SNS.
5. The end of `@Transactional` method. After return from the method Hibernate flushes all changes from the point (1) to the database (see SQL logs) and validation exception happens. But SNS message has already sent with new changes. Database has old changes because the transaction was rolled back.

**Possible solution**

You can flush database changes before publishing SNS message

```java
deviceDao.save(device.get());
deviceDao.flushChanges();  // repository.flush()
snsMessagePublisher.publishMessage(device.get());
```